# Update UICollectionViewCells sizes when UICollectionView frame is updated

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I update all the cell sizes of `UICollectionView`? 
I am changing the frame of `UICollectionView`, and want to change its UICollectionViewCells sizes accordingly

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what actually the problem is, but here is steps, that can help you to achieve what you want:

1. Define your collection view layout delegate (I assume that you use flow layout or its descendant)
2. Implement `- collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)) and compute cell size based on `collectionView`
3. When you change your collection view's frame call `invalidateLayout` (see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayout)). It will force delegate to call `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`

If you have any questions - feel free to ask. It would be better if you provide some code snippets and explain what kind of difficulties do you have.